# How to disable ngx-bootstrap modal animation?

Tags: angular, animation, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal, disable

Is there a way to disable animation for [ngx-bootstrap modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) ?

I've tried to add this config but it's not working:

```
config = {
  animated: false,
  backdrop: 'static'
};
```

**Demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-cwfhnu?file=app%2Fmodal-component%2Fstatic-modal.component.html

The modal is still showing animated.

Because in some cases the modal is showing very slow when used in a more complex web page (something like 2 seconds after a click), so may be it will be better when disabling the animation.

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2554#issuecomment-326592680 Use service, not directive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can disable animations only when using BsModalService.

Here's an example of its usage:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-k25ywj?file=app/app.component.ts

```
this.modalService.show(template, {
   animated: false
});
```

Comment: ng-template modals are not usefull in a real app, there is no way to add any custom css style for them, the documentation is very limited.

Comment: If you need some functionality that isn't provided by lib, contact ngx-bootstrap team and request it. Slack - https://ngx-slack.herokuapp.com/  Github - https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

Comment: is it also posible to disabled the animation from within the template ?